# Powershell show OU for a list of servers

Tags: list, powershell, active-directory, ou

I have a list of servers and need to find out what OU each one is in. I have searched and found something close but cannot get it to work properly. I am thinking there is a relatively easy way to do this but it eludes me. I have been trying to use the script found at the following link: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Retrieve-OU-for-Computer-7a062402
Does anyone know of an easy way to do this having it pull from a txt file using a foreach and querying against AD successfully

I tried a simple get-adcomputer servername which gave me a bunch of info including the OU, I want to build on this so it gives me just the OU for a list of servers

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Can you post the code which you have tried. It will help us to help you better!

Comment: take a look at [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Retrieve-OU-for-Computer-7a062402)

Answer (score 1):

You said you  got *a bunch of info including the OU.* I presume you mean the `DistinguishedName`, which is one property selected as default by `Get-ADComputer`. If you have the names of the servers in a text file `computers.txt`, you could do this:

```
Get-Content .\computers.txt | ForEach-Object {Get-ADComputer $_} | select DistinguishedName
```

Comment: Outstanding!!! This worked perfectly. Thank you for your assistance and taking the time to help and educate me on this. I have learned something new today :)